# Processing syntax for NetBeans 8.1

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8.1

I am new to Processing and currently use `NetBeans 8.1`. I have included the `core.jar` and using the syntax from there reference I received the following

```
When not using the PDE, size() can only be used inside settings().
Remove the size() method from setup(), and add the following:
public void settings() {
  size(600, 200);
```

Upon modification I was able to get it to work, though I don't understand what else needs to be placed in the `settings()` and what to do with the `setup()` now. I have googled this and received one hit dealing with `IntelliJ` on the Processing Forum, and the response was that somethings changed, but gave no details.

Answer (score 1):

the solutions is:

```
// Example by Diego cruz
// 26 Diciembre 2015

import processing.core.*;
public class Processing extends PApplet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main(new String[]{Processing.class.getCanonicalName()});
    }

    @Override
    public void settings() {
        size(500, 500); //
    }

    @Override
    public void setup() {

    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        rect(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
    }
}
```